# 3-point vertex in scalar non-abelian theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am considering the 3 point interaction between some scalar fields $\phi_i$, and N gluons $A^a_\mu$, indexed by a. In this Lagrangian the mass term is $\mathcal{L}_{mass} = M_{ij}\phi^*_i\phi_j $. If we have some 3-point interaction in between 2 fields and a gluon it must be $\Gamma^{a\mu}_{ij}$, and in the soft limit of the gluon it reduces to $p^\mu T^a_{ij}$, where $p^\mu$ us the scalar momentum, and $T^a$ is a constant matrix.

I'm trying to show that in  that $[
M,T^a]=0$ for the theory to be consistent. I understand that this means they are simultaneously diagonalisable and share an eigenbasis, but I don't know how to reach this conclusion.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your indices. You say there are two scalar fields so $i,j = 1,2$ but that is also an index of the generator $T^a$?

Comment: I made a mistake in the post, I've corrected it now. There are an unknown number of fields, and N gluon fields.